# What the right order of Java operators?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and just learned that the order in which the operations are carried out is determined by the precedence of each operator in the expression.
[image]

According to the picture above, the ++ and -- are evaluated first, but for example:

```java
public class StudyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        int result = -a++;
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Why the result's output is `-5`?

Comment: The increment symbol (`++`) has higher priority than negative symbol (`-`). 
But the operator `a++` is grant value of `a` first, after that increment `a` 1 value. 
You may be confused with `++a` (increment `a` 1 value then grant `a`). 
With `a = 5`, if `result = -(a++)` will show `result = -5` and `a = 6`. 
But if `result = -(++a)` will show `result = -6` and `a = 6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a++` is a *post*-increment. Which means the value is first *read as `5`* and then incremented *afterwards* (`a++` *evaluates* to `5`, but as a *side effect*, it is incremented to `6` immediately afterwards).

So `a++` evaluates to `5` inside the expression and is `6` afterwards.

Using a unitary `-` turns `5` into `-5`.

This is in contrast to the *pre-increment `++a`*, where `a` is incremented first to `6`, and *then* read.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = -a++;
```

1. ++ Has highest priority so a++ happens first; But it is post increment it returns 5 here
2. Now the Sign Operator add negative sign to 5